# What is the name of this really funny anime?

Tags: onisuki

Video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lOijDxmNxIM). (4:37 long)

Does anyone know what anime it is? Also additionally (from the same video) does anyone know if this is an actual Boy's Love Manga? Does anyone know the English translation of the title in the picture? Is it even a real life manga that I can read?

[image]

Comment: What he is reading would probably be better as a new question as we would have 2 questions here, 1) the anime identification, 2) weather or not the manga being read on it exists and if so what is the name of it.

Comment: The top says "Anthology", but the rest is hard to make out

Comment: @JonLin: 微熱男子の脈動 seems to be the title on the cover, judging from an earlier part of the video. (I figured out the last two-thirds of the title and found the rest from Google and checking with the image.)

Comment: Update: nothing came up when I looked for that in Google Images.

Comment: Those words didn't show up in any doujin db either. Maybe it's just made up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's from [Oniichan no koto nanka zenzen suki janain dakara ne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Don%27t_Like_You_at_All,_Big_Brother!) or (I don't like you at all, Big Brother!), a 12 episode anime from January, 2011, that was adapted by a manga by Kouichi Kusano.

The main character is Shusuke Takanashi:
[image]

The plot (from the wikipedia page):

> Nao Takanashi loves her brother Shūsuke despite the incest taboo. Nao thinks that Shūsuke is her blood relative, but in fact she is an adopted daughter, whose parents already died. After Nao learns the fact, she wants to normally fall in love with Shūsuke because siblings by adoption can marry under the family law in Japan. However, she finds herself competing with Shūsuke's childhood friend, Iroha Tsuchiura, and his class president and yaoi lover, Mayuka Kondō.

Mayuka Kondō is the "Kondou" that he's referring to in that video. From the wiki page:

> Shūsuke's classmate and class president, with a strong interest in Boy's Love magazines. When Shūsuke tears up one of her magazines by accident, she makes him her 'pet'. She forces him to purchase and review explicit BL magazines which she interprets as having a shared interest. Despite Shūsuke's belief that she may ask him to do something more perverted at some point, she treats him more as a boyfriend - making him bentos and coming to wake him up in time for school. Over time her feelings for Shūsuke increase because of his apparent acceptance of her BL magazines. She becomes attracted to Shūsuke's pink and sensitive nipples due to the fact she has never seen a naked man before, though despite him being her pet, she doesn't use this to her advantage. Although she confesses that she has feelings of wanting to dominate Shūsuke, he loses memory of the incident after being hit by a truck.

More info:

- [My Anime List](http://myanimelist.net/anime/9587/Onii-chan_no_Koto_Nanka_Zenzen_Suki_Janain_Dakara_ne!!)
- [Anime News Network](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=11947)

I can't make out what's on the cover of the manga, the video is really noisy.